# How can I create a image classification model?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, deep-learning

I'm new in Deep Learning and I had a problem I could not figure out for 5 days. So I am in a great disappointment. I need some help, point or something etc.

I'm trying to create a image classification model, the model looks 2 images and decide one hot 9 lenght array. like:

> [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

and two images has size 480x720 pixels.

I did try several things but compiler always saying me that

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

When I creating traning data,

```
training_data = []
...
while(loop):
    ...
    training_data.append([image1,image2, output])
    ...
    if(...):
         np.save('train_data.npy', training_data)
```

And when I reading data,

```
train = np.load('train_data.npy')
X=train[:,:2]
Y=train[:,2]

for i in range(0,len(X)):
    X[i][0] = X[i][0].reshape(-1,480,720,1)
    X[i][1] = X[i][0].reshape(-1,480,720,1)


WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 720
LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 10
OUTPUT_SHAPE= 9

model = alexnetf(WIDTH, HEIGHT,LR,OUTPUT_SHAPE)
model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=EPOCHS, validation_split=0.1, snapshot_step=500,  show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
```

I can't see any wrong for 5 days, but it doesn't working. I really need any hit, idea etc...

## plus, if you are wondering

for creating train data

```
print(type(image1)) #->(gives as output) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(image1.shape) #-> (480, 720)
print(type(image2)) #-> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(image2.shape) #-> (480, 720)
print(type(output)) #-> <class 'list'>
print(len(output))  #-> 9
```

for creating model

```
print(X.shape) #->(gives as output) (1200, 2)
print(X[0].shape) #-> (2,)
print(X[0,0].shape) #-> (1, 480, 720, 1)
print(Y.shape) #-> (1200,)
```

alexnet:

```
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
from tflearn.layers.normalization import local_response_normalization

def alexnet(width, height, lr, output):
    network = input_data(shape=[None, width, height, 1], name='input')
    network = conv_2d(network, 96, 11, strides=4, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = conv_2d(network, 256, 5, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = conv_2d(network, 384, 3, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 384, 3, activation='relu')
    network = conv_2d(network, 256, 3, activation='relu')
    network = max_pool_2d(network, 3, strides=2)
    network = local_response_normalization(network)
    network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='tanh')
    network = dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = fully_connected(network, 4096, activation='tanh')
    network = dropout(network, 0.5)
    network = fully_connected(network, output, activation='softmax')
    network = regression(network, optimizer='momentum',
                         loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                         learning_rate=lr, name='targets')

    model = tflearn.DNN(network, checkpoint_path='model_alexnet',
                        max_checkpoints=1, tensorboard_verbose=2, tensorboard_dir='log')

    return model
```

fully error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Joo/PycharmProjects/cv2/create_model.py", line 93, in <module>
    model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=EPOCHS, validation_split=0.1, snapshot_step=500,  show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
  File "D:\Program files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\models\dnn.py", line 216, in fit
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "D:\Program files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 339, in fit
    show_metric)
  File "D:\Program files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 818, in _train
    feed_batch)
  File "D:\Program files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "D:\Program files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1089, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
  File "D:\Program files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 531, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: You have to include the complete error message, including the stack trace, else the error is meaningless with out any context. The stack trace will also tell you which part of the code is producing the problem.

Comment: I edited, can you check again?

Comment: Your data is not correctly formatted (X to be precise), it seems its a ndarray that contains lists inside. That's not how it  should be done. You have two images per training sample right? The model as it is right now does not consider that.

Comment: Yes there are two images per training sample. But I don't understand why is there a problem with having lists inside ndarray? how else could it be? How can I store 2 images and 1 its output for various datas?